# Manipulating integrals containing the floor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Since $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is periodic, for $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$, we can derive the following Fourier series
$$\lfloor x\rfloor=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi kx)}{k},\quad x\notin\mathbb{Z}.$$
Is it then legal to substitute this into integrals in the following way?
$$\int dx\rho(x)\lfloor x\rfloor=? \int dx\rho(x)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi kx)}{k}\right), \quad \rho \quad\text{generic.}$$
In the application that I'm considering, I would then want to swap the order of summation and integration by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: It is legal as a direct substitution of equality. What may or may not be legal is taking the summation outside the integral.

Comment: What you can do, legally, is partition the domain of integration into integrals over integer intervals $[n,n+1]$ and maybe some intervals of the form $[b,n]$ or $[a,n]$, and replace $\lfloor x\rfloor=n$ (and bring it outside the integral!) on each such interval, and take a sum over all (finitely or infinitely many) such partitioning-interval.

Comment: Thanks! actually in my problem I have $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ instead of $\lfloor x\rfloor$. Don't ask me why, physics is perverse...